# Python 3, if str is present replace with str

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I'm writing a fairly simple python program to find and download videos from a particular site. I would like to have my script name the file by using the page title except the page title contains various strings i would like remove for e.g.,

```
The title is: 
The Big Bang Theory S09E15 720p HDTV X264-DIMENSION
```

but the titles are not always consistent for e.g.,

```
The title is:
Triple 9 2016 READNFO HDRip AC3-EVO
```

How can I replace strings if they are present?
Maybe create a list or dictionary of possible strings and if they are present then remove them (or replace with empty string)? I have tried and tried to find an answer but cannot find anything that helps my situation.

Basically if `"HDTV", "HDRip", "720p", "X264", etc` are present then replace them otherwise carry on?

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? You've used [tag:regex], have you *tried writing a regex?*

Comment: Basically it's find `HDTV|HDRip|720p|X264`, replace with nothing.

Comment: @Jack Refer the dupe, It solves your problem exactly. Also a related problem is [Censoring a text string using a dictionary and replacing words with Xs. Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16675634)

Answer (score 3):

Simple example:

```
string = 'The Big Bang Theory S09E15 720p HDTV X264-DIMENSION'
dict = {'720p':'1080p'} # format 'substring':'replacement'

for key, value in dict.iteritems():
  if key in string:
    string.replace(key,value)
```

The only problem with this is that if you want to replace a word that could be part of another word. For example if you want to replace 'an' with a, then the string in this example would become 'The Big Bag Theory ... '. To fix this I would try breaking up the string into a set of words and compare the words to dictionary entries.

Comment: This should be the best answer out of all...

Answer (score 2):

```
for undesired_word in ("HDTV", "HDRip", "720p", "X264"):
    title = title.replace(undesired_word, "")
```

Comment: It's too slow this way, use a regex with alternations and do it in one shot.

Comment: @Kevin could I do `dict = {'720p':'1080p'} for undesired_word in dict: title = title.replace(undesired_word, "")`, I' fairly new to 'non-basic' python so still learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
title = 'The Big Bang Theory S09E15 720p HDTV X264-DIMENSION'

if 'HDTV' in title:
    title = title.replace('HDTV', '')
```

not very pythonic but it will do what you want

Comment: Not much point in having the conditional there. if HDTV isn't in the title, then `title = title.replace('HDTV', '')` doesn't do anything, so it's harmless to run it anyway.

Comment: good to know, I figured title.replace would return traceback if the unwanted word wasnt present

Answer (score 0):

Kevins answer will work for you, but just in case you find yourself wanting to use a `regex`:

```
import re
string_to_replace = ["HDTV", "HDRip", "720p", "X264"]
regex_string = r"|".join(string_to_replace)
S = "The Big Bang Theory S09E15 720p HDTV X264-DIMENSION"
new_string = re.sub(regex_string, "", S, flags=re.I)
print(new_string)
```

prints:

```
The Big Bang Theory S09E15   -DIMENSION
```

Also, as you will notice the spaces that went after the strings you were replacing are still there, if you do not want that, you can change `string_to_replace` to include the spaces, like so: `["HDTV ", "HDRip ", "720p ", "X264 "]` and this would result in the output being:

```
The Big Bang Theory S09E15 X264-DIMENSION
```

Comment: @ ZWiki thanks that seems like my preference so far but to evaluate what does "|" represent please?

Comment: @JackHerer, oh sorry. The "|" is like a logical OR. This joins the string so that it would produce "HDTV|HDRip|720p|x264" which in a regex means if it matches any of those strings, replace it with nothing. The `flags=re.I` is also ignore case, which you can get rid of if you want it to be `case sensitive`

Comment: @ ZWiki ..excellent explanation, cheers, and I am replacing spaces with hyphens after replacing undesired strings